# mysqli prepared multiple statements search not excuting

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to transition my old Mysqli queries to mysqli prepared statements, and I don't seem able to figure out how to get this working as a mysqli prepared statements - see my code below. My original query works fine see below.

```
<?php

// DB Settings
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'xxxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxx');
define('DB_NAME', 'xxxx'); 

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$name = "Smith"; //Smith is Master 6 times and once as Junior Stewart Total 7 rows in my database
$search_query = '%'.$name.'%';
//Original Query - this works fine
$sql = "SELECT Master, `Junior Steward` AS `Junior_Steward` FROM past_officers WHERE `Master` LIKE 

'$search_query' OR `Junior Steward` LIKE '$search_query' ";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($mysqli);

if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $search_query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $Master, $Junior_Steward);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
    printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt));//Prints number of rows

    if ($count == 0) { 
        echo $output = "<p>There was no search results</p>"; //asign to variable $output message "There was no search results"
    }
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        echo "<p>Master: $Master Junior Steward: $Junior_Steward</p>";
    }
}

/* Prepared Statements Binds two variables to a prepared statement as parameters*/
//This doesn't work
$sql = "SELECT Master, `Junior Steward` AS `Junior_Steward` FROM past_officers WHERE `Master` LIKE ? OR `Junior 

Steward` LIKE ?";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($mysqli);

if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $search_query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $Master, $Junior_Steward);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
    printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt));//Prints number of rows

    if ($count == 0) { 
        echo $output = "<p>There was no search results</p>"; //asign to variable $output message "There was no search results"
    }

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        echo "<p>Master: $Master Junior Steward: $Junior_Steward</p>";
    }
}


/* Prepared Statements Bind one variable to a prepared statement as parameters*/
//This works but only for one parameter
$sql = "SELECT Master FROM past_officers WHERE `Master` LIKE ? ";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($mysqli);

if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $search_query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $Master);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
    printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt));//Prints number of rows

    if ($count == 0) { 
        echo $output = "<p>There was no search results</p>"; //asign to variable $output message "There was no search results"
    }
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        echo "<p>Master: $Master </p>";
    }
}


$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close()
?>
```

Comment: So if you put two `?` placeholders and bind only one what did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You are using both the class mysqli and the functions from mysqli. You are not actually using one of them.
Choose between one of them, or use the class or use the functions like mysqli_connect();
Here is an example of how you should execute prepared statements using the class mysqli.

```
$stmt = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$username = "Jordy";
$password = "MyLittleSecret";

if($query = $stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?")) {
    $query->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $query->execute();
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php